# At most two of the three polynomials $p(x)$, $p(x) - 1$, $p(x) - c$ are squares in $k[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to show the following statement: Let $k$ be a field (no assumptions about algebraic closure or similar). Let $c \in k$ be a constant, which is not $1$ or $0$. Let $p(x) \in k[x]$ be a nonconstant polynomial, then $q(x) := p(x)(p(x) - 1)(p(x) - c)$ is not a square in $k[x]$.

It seems to me that under the assumption of $k$ being algebraically closed this reduces to what the title states, by observing that the three factors are coprime and hence share no roots, so every root of $p(x)$, $p(x) - 1$, and $p(x) - c$ would have multiplicity $2$ if $q(x)$ was a square, hence they would all be squares.

1. Does this reduction of the problem work when $k$ is not algebraically closed?
2. If yes, how can one show the statement in the title?
3. If no, how does one show the statement in the first paragraph without this reduction? Is it even true?

I was not able to find any counterexample to the statement of the first paragraph (I mostly looked at fields of characteristic $2$). It should be true as it is equivalent to an exercise from an algebraic geometry class I am currently taking, although that exercise could be lacking assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $k$ is algebraically closed and its characteristic is distinct from $2$, it seems that you cannot even have *two* "consecutive squares"; that is, $P$ and $P-1$ cannot both be squares (unless they are constant polynomials). To see this, assume for a contradiction that this is possible, and let $P$ and $P-1$ are polynomials of the smallest possible (positive) degree which are both squares; say, $P=Q^2$ and $P-1=R^2$. Then $R^2=Q^2-1=(Q-1)(Q+1)$, and since $Q-1$ and $Q+1$ are coprime, they are both squares: $Q-1=U^2$, $Q+1=V^2$. It follows that $V^2-U^2=2$, and therefore $V^2/2$ and $V^2/2-1$ is yet another pair of "consecutive squares" (recall that $k$ is algebraically closed), while $\deg (V^2/2)=\deg Q=(\deg P)/2<\deg P$, a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, that's nice! Perhaps a similar minimality argument could work when removing the assumptions of characteristic and closure, while in turn adding the assumption of three not two polynomials. I am not sure though.

Comment: As far as I see, closeness is not an issue. If $k$ is not closed, then consider its algebraic closure $K$. Now $P$ and $P-1$ can be considered as polynomials over $K$, and as we saw, they cannot both be squares of polynomials over $K$. All the more, they cannot be squares of polynomials over $k$. The same seems to apply to your reduction.

Comment: You would have got faster the conclusion and can drop the condition on the characteristic if you do $(Q+R)(Q-R)=Q^2-R^2=1$, which implies that $Q+R$ and $Q-R$ are both constant polynomials, which implies that $Q$ and $R$ are constant.

Comment: I think this works. I am a bit dumbfounded however, since I feel like I should have known this trick. Do you know a good source on exercises (or just a book containing propositions with proofs that use these tricks) like these about polynomials? (tricks like choosing polynomials of minimal degree, replacing by algebraic closure, factoring $Q^2 - R^2$ etc.)

Comment: @JohnVick: unfortunately, I do not know such a book. (Why not ask here at MSE as a separate question?)

Comment: @logarithm: not that it were really faster, and there is no way to drop the characteristic condition because the statement is wrong in characteristic $2$, consider $x^2$ and $x^2+1$.